# TrueSTUDIO look and feel

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, ide, truestudio

I have used Keil uVision and Microchip MPLABX IDE's a lot for various MCUs. Now starting to use Atollic TrueSTUDIO for STM32 MCUs.

But even after spending many weeks on trueSTUDIO and building many small example codes in it.. i still do not feel comfortable as it was in the other 2 IDEs mentioned above. It was more easy to see the code and focus on it in those IDE's while the trueSTUDIO has so many views on the window that keeps you distracting and its difficult to keep focus on the code..

1. Can anyone suggest how to make the look and feel of trueSTUDIO simple?
2. Someone told me that it's possible to use some other editor like Notepad++ for code writing and the compiler, linker etc toolchain from the trueSTUDIO. Is it advisable and how can that be done?

Comment: I just close all the windows except project explorer and the actual code editing tabs. Is there a reason you can't just do this? It's not the best editor in the world, but not the worst either. Underneath it is just GCC so getting it going on another editor is pretty trivial (web tutorials abound). Getting the debugger going nicely is a different story, hence why I still stick with trueStudio.

Comment: I've never used trueSTUDIO, but can't you just close the views you don't want to see?

Comment: I close views but then they reappear off and on while i change perspectives or go from screen to screen.. also for every new project its tedious thing to set the views manually. Is there any global permanent setting to enable/disable specific views?

Comment: It's yet another Total Eclipse, in which case the solution is: turn around. Basically, you get what you pay for. What's your tool budget like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TrueStudio is Eclipse-based, this means that you can create custom perspectives and can configure them to your liking, including saving and restoring them. You might want to look at the [Eclipsepedia](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Main_Page) for guidance on everything related to the Eclipse environment.

Comment: is there any file that holds all the settings of screen perspectives and views? are these settings workspace based or project based?

Comment: Not sure about all of them but usually that information is stored somewhere in the workspace root directory you specified at the first start.

Comment: Google says: %SuperFolder%\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workbench.xml ... but I haven't tested that .. it's probably also dependent on the actual version